# tensorflow-using dynamic shape when defining models

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a batch of input:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [NUM_SAMPLE, None, 15])
```

For each one in the batch, I have a dictionary that describes the relationship of rows. It looks like:

```
dic = {i:{j:rij,k:rik,...},j:{i:rij,l:rjl,...},...}
```

Now I wanna do this for each sample and corresponding dic:

```
updated_sample = sample
for i in range(len(sample)):
    for j in dic[i]:
        tmp = concanate(sample[j],rij)
        updated_sample[i] += matmul(tmp,W)
```

in which W is the same for all samples and rows.

However, I cannot use len(sample) in tensorflow. It seems `tf.while_loop` may be the answer, but I don't know how to use it in this problem. Any suggestions?

Besides, can I use dictionary in this way in tensorflow?

Comment: I have tried to transform it into pure tensor-multiplication, but the resulting model costs too much memory ( it needs a rank-4 tensor of the shape `len(sample)*len(sample)*16*16` for each sample) and is thus useless.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 analogs in tensorflow for `len(sample)`:

- tf.shape(sample)[0]
- sample.get_shape().as_list()[0]

The first one, `tf.shape(sample)` returns a tensor of integers of length equal to the rank of the tensor, doing `tf.shape(sample)[0]` is a tensor with shape `()` and should be used within the tenosrflow workflow.

The second one, `sample.get_shape()` returns a Tensor.shape object, doing `sample.get_shape().as_list()` transforms this into a list of integers.

In your case, you should to use the second of these.

Consider also the option of doing this computations at the numpy level, and then input them into the graph through placeholders.

Comment: I'll have a try of get_shape, thanks. Besides, I want to repeat this computation for certain rounds, so maybe it's difficult to do it at numpy level?